# How can I place multiple html buttons that act as links on the same page?

Tags: html, button

Does any one know how I can place multiple html buttons that act as links  on the same html page?

I am currently doing this:

```
<form action="http://justchillinc.wix.com/just-chill">       
    <input type="submit" value="Just Chill">
</form>
<form action="http://google.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Google">
</form>
```

Comment: Err… like that. Although you should use links if you want links and CSS if you want them to *look* like buttons.

Comment: You can use the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link?rq=1

Comment: How do you use the <a> tag?

Comment: just make `a` tag and then style is through css by either targeting the `a` directly or assign a `class` or `id` to it then style that.

Answer (score 1):

not styled brilliant but you get the idea... any a tag with a class of button will be styled the same.

```css
.button{
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:yellow;
  font-weight:bold;
  min-width:132px;
  min-height:37px;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius:12px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:gray;
  box-shadow:8px 8px 8px gray;
  margin:10px;
  
  }
.button:active{
  background-color:green;
position:relative;
  top:8px;
  left:8px;

}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" class="button" target="_blank">Link Here</a>
<a href="http://google.com" class="button" target="_blank">Link Here</a>
<a href="http://google.com" class="button" target="_blank">Link Here</a>
<a href="http://google.com" class="button" target="_blank">Link Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it is already good. Here are some other methods to do this:

1. With the `a` tag and some custom css (http://jsfiddle.net/pp4eufat/)

   HTML:

   ```
   <a class="button" href="http://justchillinc.wix.com/just-chill">Just chill</a>
   ```

   CSS:

   ```
   a.button {
       padding: 5px 10px;
       background-color: #ddd;
       color: #222;
       text-decoration: none;
   }
   ```

   You can easily assign the button class to submit buttons or similar to get a consistent button look all over your page.
2. With a button and javascript (http://jsfiddle.net/gdfx5fd3/)

   Code:

   ```
   <button onclick="window.location.href='http://google.com';">Google</button>
   ```

   The important part is `onclick="location.href='http://google.com';"`. It tells the browser to open `http://google.com` when the user clicks the button. The disadvantage is that the user has to have javascript enabled (nearly everybody has it enabled, so this isn't a big problem)

Answer (score 0):

From:

```
<form action="http://justchillinc.wix.com/just-chill">       
    <input type="submit" value="Just Chill">
</form>
<form action="http://google.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Google">
</form>
```

To:

```
<form method="post" action="http://justchillinc.wix.com/just-chill">       
    <input type="submit" value="Just Chill">
</form>
<form method="post" action="http://google.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Google">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to create multiple links if you didn't want to copy and paste the same link.

```html
<button class= "card" id="card-1">1</button>
<button class= "card" id="card-2">2</button>
<button class= "card" id="card-3">3</button>
<button class= "card" id="card-4">4</button>
<button class= "card" id="card-5">5</button>
<button class= "card" id="card-6">6</button>
<button class= "card" id="card-7">7</button>
<button class= "card" id="card-8">8</button>
<button class= "card" id="card-">9</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i ++)
    {
        (function(){
        elements[i].onclick = function () {
        location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888246/how-can-i-place-multiple-html-buttons-that-act-as-links-on-the-same-page#";
        };}());
    };
</script>
```